# Issue Inflating Custom layout

Tags: android, android-tabhost, android-tabs, tabwidget

I am inflating custom layout for my tabwidget Tab . But as soon as i inflate custom layout for my last tab, my bottom tab widget goes full screen .

**What i want**:
[image]

**What's happening :**

[image]

**TabActivity Code:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            // Check if GCM configuration is set
                if (CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL == null || CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID == null || CommonUtilities.SERVER_URL.length() == 0
                        || CommonUtilities.SENDER_ID.length() == 0) {
                    // GCM sernder id / server url is missing

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Configuration Error!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    // stop executing code by return
                     return;
                }

            context = getApplicationContext();
               // TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();
                tabHost = getTabHost(); 
                SharedPreferences preferences2 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
                String u_id1 = preferences2.getString("Userid","");
                Bean b = new Bean();
                b.setDeviceid(u_id1);

             // Tab for Photos
                TabSpec photospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Favourite");        photospec.setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_favourites_tab,null));
                Intent photosIntent = new Intent(this, Favourite.class);


            photospec.setContent(photosIntent);

            // Tab for Songs
                TabSpec songspec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Contacts");
                // setting Title and Icon for the Tab

                songspec.setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_contacts_tab,null));
    //          songspec.setIndicator("Contacts", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tab_contacts));
                Intent songsIntent = new Intent(this, Contacts.class);
                songspec.setContent(songsIntent);

                // Tab for Videos
                TabSpec videospec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Meeting");
                videospec.setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_meeting_tab,null));
                Intent videosIntent = new Intent(this, Meeting.class);
                videospec.setContent(videosIntent);
             // Tab for Future SMS
                TabSpec futuresms = tabHost.newTabSpec("Map");
            futuresms.setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_map_tab,null));
                Intent futureIntent = new Intent(this, Map.class);
                futuresms.setContent(futureIntent);

                // Tab for Future SMS

    //Inflating custom layout for all tabs 

                TabSpec setting = tabHost.newTabSpec("Setting");
             setting.setIndicator(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_setting_tab,null));
                Intent settingintent = new Intent(this, Setting.class);
                setting.setContent(settingintent);

            // Adding all TabSpec to TabHost
                tabHost.addTab(photospec); // Adding photos tab
                tabHost.addTab(songspec); // Adding songs tab
                tabHost.addTab(videospec); // Adding videos tab
                tabHost.addTab(futuresms);
                tabHost.addTab(setting);



            for (int i = 0; i <tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
                tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.button_color));

            }
    tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tab_click);

               String tabid = Bean.getDeviceid();
               if(tabid == null)
               {
                   int in = Integer.parseInt("2");
                    tabHost.setCurrentTab(in);
               }
               else
               {
                int in = Integer.parseInt(tabid);
                tabHost.setCurrentTab(in);
               }



             }



        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
              editor.putString("msg","Hi");

            super.onDestroy();
        }

        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onBackPressed();
            System.gc();
            MainActivity.this.finish();
            System.exit(0);
 } 

    }
```

**Tab.xml**:

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:background="@android:color/white"
     >
     <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
              android:background="@android:color/white"


            />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
              android:background="@color/button_color"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false"
             />

    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

**Custom_layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@color/button_color"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageview"
                android:theme="@style/tablayout"
                android:background="@drawable/tab_setting"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>


            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Settings"
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@color/button_pressed"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/view"
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#2ca4dc" />


    </LinearLayout>
```

> Please help me finiding bug in my code or some other approach .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is happening because of    android:layout_height="match_parent" change with wrap_content.

Custom layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageview"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/oryx_logo" />


        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/textview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Settings"
            android:textColor="@color/future_color"
            android:textSize="10sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#2ca4dc" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You saved my hours . thanks alot . Such small issue . Thanks a ton . Also request you to upvote the question . Gratefull